# Spacecraft pulled by the moon

Tags: moons, gravity, spaceships

The idea is- as the moon is passing over, the pull of Earth's gravity on immediate area surrounding the spacecraft somehow temporarily cancelled out (still working on the how) and the craft *falls* toward the moon. After clearing Earth's atmosphere the craft's thrusters (or other means of propulsion) direct the vessel away from the moon to avoid crashing into it.

Assuming a way to nullify Earth's pull exists (asking a lot, I know), how light would the spacecraft need to be? What likely velocity would the 'moonfall' (for lack of a better phrase) have for say, a two-person craft?

Comment: If you can nullify gravity, why not nullify gravity on *both* objects? Presumably, if you can't do it partially, you can use something like PWM to generate controlled thrust.

Comment: How: [cavorite](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=717).

Comment: I believe that Larry Niven used the idea of selective gravitational attraction in the gravity planer (the "Kzinti drive"). Everything old is new again...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work. Using the formula for gravitational attraction: $$F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$ and plugging in $m_1=7.34767309×10^{22} kg$ for the mass of the moon and $r=363,104 km$ for the distance of the moon (at its closest), we get $$a = 3.71945379 × 10^{-5} \frac{m}{s^2}$$

Meaning that after about 7.5 hours of acceleration using only the moon's pull, you'd *finally* be able to get up to the blazing fast speed of... 1 meter per second. That's a slow walking pace. And that is if the moon were to be pulling consistently in the same direction, so you'd first have to solve the (*much*) harder problem of getting the moon to stay still.

Yeah... not gonna work.

Comment: Also, in case you're not aware, the mass of the object doesn't matter - it will accelerate at the same rate whether it's a pea or Mount Everest.

Comment: Actually, it'll work fine. Assume that the full moon is directly overhead at local midnight. If you launch from the equator at midnight, equatorial velocity (463 m/sec) will get you to the moon's orbit in about 10 days. Since the moon took 7 days to reach that point, there's some catchup involved, but if you launched at about 9 PM 3 days before the full moon, that should about do it.

Answer (score 0):

How: [cavorite](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=717).  That's so 19th century though.

But a variation of the idea was used in "hard" SF by Wil McCarthy.  He wrote of a "gravar", a gravity laser. Essentially a tractor beam that can make the craft attracted *strongly* to any body, specifically including the moon.

You still need to put energy in to accelerate: it just gives you a "rope" to pull on.

Comment: As I noted above - Larry Niven, Kzinti gravity planer.